# In same document object i have a page in which i need my default document renderer in half page and in second half also need ColumnDocumentRenderer

Tags: itext7

I have created documents using itext 7 and its `ColumnDocumentRenderer`.  But In same document object I have a page in which I need my default document renderer in half page and in second half also need `ColumnDocumentRenderer`. How can I achieve this in same document page?

I have overridden `ColumnDocumentRenderer` to create my own based on a flag it returns super default renderer else it returns `ColumnDocumentRenderer`.

But still on same page I am not able to get both renderers, it always uses first one which I have c

Comment: Could you provide a sketch of the layout you want? I don't understand it from the description alone.

Comment: Have you considered using a `ColumnDocumentRenderer` with three rectangles, the first with the upper half of the page content area, and the second and third containing the lower left and the lower right quarter of it? With the appropriate `AreaBreak` you can jump to the next rectangle...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Renderers per iText document: Updated with more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854402/multiple-renderers-per-itext-document-updated-with-more-details)