# Multiple Renderers per iText document: Updated with more details

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am using iText7 to create a document which has multiple sections. Some of the sections are to be formatted normally, but some are to be formatted into columns. I can get it to format properly into columns by using the ColumnDocumentRenderer object, but when I do so, the *entire document* is set to use columns. Is there any way to have iText swap which renderer to use on the fly?

When I try to swap out renderers on the fly, I get a null pointer exception (com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.get(PdfDictionary.java:482)).

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(targetFile));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
DocumentRenderer defRender = new DocumentRenderer(document);
document.setRenderer(defRender);
ColumnDocumentRenderer dictRender = getColumnRender();

while (<CONDITION>) {
    document.setRenderer(dictRender);
    document.add(new Paragraph("THIS IS NORMAL TEXT"));
    document.add(new Paragraph("THIS IS NORMAL TEXT"));
    document.add(new Paragraph("THIS IS NORMAL TEXT"));
    <...> 
    document.setRenderer(defRender);
    document.add(new Paragraph("THIS IS COLUMN TEXT"));
    document.add(new Paragraph("THIS IS COLUMN TEXT"));
    document.add(new Paragraph("THIS IS COLUMN TEXT"));
    <...>
}
```

After I set the renderer to dictRender, the first document.add() statement throws a null pointer error at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.get(PdfDictionary.java:482).

I don't want to have to create multiple different PDF files, but am thinking that might be what I end up having to do. Thanks for any help here.

Comment: *When I try to swap out renderers on the fly* - how do you try? If you show, probably someone can improve your solution.

Comment: Updated with a specific code example. If you could take a look at this and let me know if anything stands out to you, I'd be really appreciative! ^^

Comment: In the loop you always set the `dictRender`. Did you mean that?

Comment: Ack, that came from me simplifying the code when I copied it over. I am changing the renderer in my code, and the example has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: OK. And what is your expectation when you switch renderers? Is it OK for the new renderer to start on a new page or do you expect the remaining current page to be filled by the new renderer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception occurs because page content is flushed as soon as it is possible by default to save memory.

To avoid immediate flushing of content, there is a parameter of `DocumentRenderer` and `ColumnDocumentRenderer` constructors.

So, for instance, to create a `DocumentRenderer` with immediate flushing switched off, you would have to create it as follows:

```
DocumentRenderer defRender = new DocumentRenderer(document, false);
```

It is very similar for `ColumnDocumentRenderer`.

Next, as you have switched off automatic flushing and change renderers by yourself, in the end of your code, just before `document.close();`, you would have to manually flush your renderers:

```
defRender.flush();
dictRender.flush();
```

Now the content appears, though still the result may look ugly because of content overlapping. This is up to the developer to resolve, because two renderers are independent instances and they maintain `currentArea` independent of each other. To handle this appropriately, you would have to update `currentArea` of the renderer you are going to switch to with the `currentArea` of the previous renderer you have just finished working with. You can do that by extending the standard provided renderers, or calling `renderer.getCurrentArea()` and modifying the `bBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice there! I will implement this and confirm the answer as soon as I'm able. Figuring out how to synchronize the lengths of the document will be something I just have to put together on my own if it's not included with the standard iText patterns here.

Comment: I have updated the [iText 7: building blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/) tutorial. See [chapter 2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) and look for the title **Switching between different renderers** or take a look at the [JekyllHydeV6](http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/3186/draft#1900-c02e10_jekyllhydev6.java) example.