# iText 7change document renderer and continue on the last position

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

How do you change the `DocumentRenderer` in iText7 and continue on the corect position? I need some paragraphs to be rendered in 2 columns, and then normal text.

This is what I have, but it not works as expected:

```cs
using (MemoryStream oDocumentStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfWriter oDocumentWriter = new PdfWriter(oDocumentStream).SetSmartMode(true))
    {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(oDocumentWriter);  
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        float offSet = 60;
        float columnWidth = (PageSize.A4.GetWidth() - offSet * 2 + 10) / 2;
        float columnHeight = PageSize.A4.GetHeight() - offSet * 2;

        //Define column areas
        Rectangle[] columns = new Rectangle[] 
        {
            new Rectangle(offSet - 5, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
            new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight)
        };

        document.SetRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns)); //First renderer
        document.Add(*myparagraph*);
        document.SetRenderer(new iText.Layout.Renderer.DocumentRenderer(document)); //Second renderer
        document.Add(*myparagraph*);
        document.Close();
    }

    oPdfFile = oDocumentStream.ToArray();
}
```

The issue with this approach is that the second renderer don't continue where the first renderer ended, therefore they overlap, as you can see in this image:

[image: rendering is overlaping]

Comment: 1) You can absolutely switch between renderers.  2) I'd suggest declaring a new variable for each different renderer (rather than leaving them "anonymous".  3) Google for "itext7 switch between renderers":  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38890352/421195, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62438890/421195, 
 or https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-java/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers

Comment: Those examples don't have the answer for my question. I've tries every one of them, but the result is not what I intend.

Comment: You mention that you need some paragraphs to be rendered in 2 columns, and then normal text. To be honest I don't see any differences from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434598/how-to-switch-different-itext-document-renderers-in-the-same-page/62438890#62438890. You mentioned you tried to implement based on the answer from that question - can you add the code of that approach? You can just start from that answer, make sure it works and work from it to modify to your needs